# How do I group my data by hour?

Tags: r

I have read my data into R, where I am trying to group my data by hour with the code below:

```
tweets <- read.csv("tweetCSV.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

tweets %>%
group_by(format(Time, "%H"), Word) %>%
summarise(count=n())
```

When I run this code I get an error (shown below) which I cannot get my head around:

- "Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : invalid 'trim' argument"

I was wondering if anybody can help me overcome this problem?

Thanks James

Sample of the data-set is accessible via this link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JhXEyzkjPs59hVgoS3lW7e0Fcumis62QDUvuMP2q5aQ/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
tweets %>%
    mutate(Time = as.POSIXct(Time)) %>%
    group_by(lubridate::hour(Time), Word) %>%
    summarise(count=n()) %>%
    arrange(desc(count))
```

Converting it to a POSIXct lets you use lubridate's hour function which is handy.

Comment: Thank you that works, really appreciate the help :-) I have been spending ages to get this to work. @Adrian Martin I was wondering if you know of any good sources to learn more about using dplyr with lubridate?

Comment: I learned them separately. It takes a little while to get comfortable with dplyr. Lubridate is pretty simple to learn - just call "str()" on your data all the time to figure out what class everything is. I recommend using the RStudio cheat sheet on dplyr that's here: https://www.rstudio.com/resources/cheatsheets/.