# How can can I group data by hour and retain the field with time and date ("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")?

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I have ten minute data I am trying to aggregate into hourly data. I am using a POSIXct formatted time field. I found a similar question posed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43262965/how-do-i-group-my-data-by-hour). I would like to group the data by hour, but retain a POSIXct formatted field for each hour for the year ("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"). In addition, I am hoping to retain all the fields in my original dataframe except what I am passing through to summarize using dplyr. I am encountering problems using group_by_at, which elicits the following error:

> Error in as.POSIXlt.default(x, tz = tz(x)) :    do not know how to
>   convert 'x' to class “POSIXlt”

When I try to just use group_by, it works, but converts the ymd_hms format into just %h. Is there a way to keep this format intact when grouping by hour? Is there a more efficient way to group the ten minute data into an hourly format?

Here is an example of what works, but removes the ymd_hms format:

```
summary_df <- long_df %>%
  group_by(hour = lubridate::hour(time), discrete_variable) %>%
  summarise(max_continuous_variable = max(continuous_variable))
```

Comment: Try giving it a column name, e.g., `group_by(hour = lubridate::hour(time), discrete_variable)`. If that doesn't work, please share some sample input data. Also, your title and text say `group_by_at`, but your code example uses `group_by`. Probably best if those are aligned.

Comment: I don't get what you mean. You call a function that returns the hour number of a date, but then don't want the number of the date...? I don't think that has anything to do with `group_by`, seems like just you're calling a function that's not the one you want

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion, I modified my question to show that I am specifically interested in keeping the source column that contains the full time and date in the format "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" after grouping by hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest `lubridate::floor_date` for this. It will round down to the last hour, giving you a datetime for grouping.

```
summary_df <- long_df %>%
  group_by(hour = lubridate::floor_date(time, "1 hour"), discrete_variable) %>%
  summarise(max_continuous_variable = max(continuous_variable))
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, this method worked well. I was able to keep the other variables by specifically calling them out in the group_by section of the pipe.

Answer (score 0):

I asked a colleague, who was able to provide an answer that worked for me. I wanted to share the successful result in case this is relevant to others. Using summarise and applying min(time) after grouping worked to retain the time field that has "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S".

```
summary_df <- long_df %>%
  group_by(hour = lubridate::hour(time), discrete_variable) %>%
  summarise(max_continuous_variable = max(continuous_variable),
            time = min(time))
```

Comment: To be clear, that will retain the `minimum` value of `time` for each group. You could also do the maximum, the average, the first, the last, or any other function, as long as it returns one time per group. You could keep all rows (including the original column) by using `mutate` instead of `summarise`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @Gregor!