# How can I group time by 24 hours of day - datetime

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate

```
rides_id <- c("A3F8D895163BBB49", "0D139A3203274B87", "C7AE8E9CDB197A8E", "2633EB2B8A99F5CB")
users_ride <- c("member", "casual", "member", "casual")
start_time <- c("2021-01-01 00:12:39", "2021-01-01 03:08:39", "2021-01-01 14:26:36", "2021-01-01 17:20:06")

trip_data <- data.frame(rides_id,users_ride,start_time)

print(trip_data)
```

I want to count rides_id by 24hour of day and group by users_ride. For example, at 6 am how many rides_ids are grouped by users_type? so I can create a graph like the one below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWg6z.png)

Please help me, Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I group my data by hour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43262965/how-do-i-group-my-data-by-hour)

Comment: `trip_data$hours<-lubridate::hour(trip_data$start_time);
table(trip_data$hours, trip_data$users_ride)`

Comment: For the graph you can do a variation of `ggplot(data=trip_data, aes(x=start_time)) + geom_line(stat="count", aes(color=users_ride))`